# How to share variable between two child process (in both kernel and user space) in Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory-address

I have a scenario that Process A forks two child process called PB and PC. And there is a variable `X` will be modified by PB and PC in **user space**. Also, `X` will be modified by PB and PC in **kernel space**.

What I have done is make PB allocate user virtual address by `aligned_alloc` and pass it into kernel (by hooking system call), using `get_user_pages` + `kmap` to get kernel virtual address. In this way, `X` can be shared in PB's kernel and user space.

My question is how to let PC to modify `X` in both kernel and user space?

Following is what I proposed but still remain questionable.

1. function `page_to_phys` can convert `struct page` into physical address, then PC can get user virtual address by mapping device `/dev/mem` with given physical address. In this way, PC can modify `X` in user space.
2. I can get virtual kernel address by let PC to call `kmap` with `struct page` which is returned from `page_to_phys`. In this way, PC can modify `X` in kernel space. But I'm not sure `struct page` is context-dependent or not. Can PC use this `page` which is the result called by PB?

Comment: What you're doing doesn't make much sense and it's really bad practice. Why not just use a normal syscall or ioctl that you can easily register with a kernel module and then `copy_{to,from}_user()`? That's how it should be done.

Comment: In my case, modification will be frequent, I expect `copy_{to,from}_user()` would hamper the performance.

Comment: The overhead of a `copy_{to,from}_user` is *none* compared to that of a system call, which as I understand you will have to do every single time you want the kernel to modify the data. So really you are trying to solve an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).